# How to calculate query result on the bases of percentage

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to calculate query result on the bases of percentage, which is set from the admin panel of the website.
There are four status for the same.
Gold, Silver,Bronze and Medellin.
My current formula is

```
select * , isnull( CASE WHEN RowNumber <=  (@totaltopPromoters*@Gold/100) Then 1
                       WHEN RowNumber >= (@totaltopPromoters*@Gold/100) and RowNumber <= (@totaltopPromoters*@Gold/100) + (@totaltopPromoters*@Silver/100) THEN 2 
                       WHEN RowNumber>=(@totaltopPromoters*@Silver/100) and RowNumber<= (@totaltopPromoters*@Gold/100)+(@totaltopPromoters*@Silver/100)  + (@totaltopPromoters*@Bronze/100)THEN 3 
                       WHEN RowNumber>=(@totaltopPromoters*@Medallion/100) and RowNumber <= (@totaltopPromoters*@Gold/100)+(@totaltopPromoters*@Silver/100)  + (@totaltopPromoters*@Bronze/100)+(@totaltopPromoters*@Medallion/100) THEN 4
                       end ,0) as  
                    TrophyType
```

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, at least to me. Could you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve? Also, which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: what error are you facing?